# Importing SQL Table in Laravel and generating passwords from Column

Tags: sql, laravel, hash, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I want to import an old Symfony users table in my Laravel project. The old passwordcolumn is hashed with sha1 and some of them with md5.

What would be the easiest way to import the user table and generate the passwords from i.e. the username column?